# How to create spring properties by condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to create a `application.properties` property by condition?

I want to define a filename that should be "default_name_test" if `spring.profiles.active=test`, and "default_name" otherwise.

Pseudeocode:

```
#application.properties:
filename=default_name${spring.profiles.active} = test ? "_test" : "";
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Why can't you use a profile-specific properties file?

Comment: That would be a workaroud, yes

Comment: I don't consider it a workaround, since it is fully supported for exactly this use case as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dave Syer already mentioned in his comment, it is possible to use profile specific property files to configure the application with Spring Boot. So in your `application.properties` you define the property with its default value, and in the file `application-test.properties` you define the property with default_name_test. The name pattern for the config files is `application-${profilename}.properties`.

See the Spring Boot manual here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties